# Swift 1.2: override init gives error

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ios8.3

In my project I have many subclasses of UIView.

Some of them I override the init() method

```
// Worked in Swift 1.1
override init() {
    super.init()
}
```

Now I get this error:

> Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass

From the error message it seems like Apple decided to remove the init() method from UIView... But I still can create a new UIView but doing

```
let view = UIView()
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I assume UIView() calls initWithFrame:CGRectZero or something.